# OpenMP: How to copy back value of firstprivate variable back to global

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I am new to OpenMP and I am stuck with a basic operation. Here is a sample code for my question.

```
#include <omp.h>
int main(void)
{
  int A[16] = {1,2,3,4,5 ...... 16};
  #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(A)
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
     for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
     {
         A[i*4+j] = Process(A[i*4+j]);
     }
  }
}
```

As evident,value of A is local to each thread. However, at the end, I want to write back part of A calculated by each threadto the corresponding position in global variable A. How this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Simply make `A` *shared*. This is fine, because all loop iterations operate on separate elements of `A`. Remember that OpenMP is *shared memory* programming.

You can do so explicitly by using `shared` instead of `firstprivate`, or simply remove the declaration:

```
  int A[16] = {1,2,3,4,5 ...... 16};
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

By default all variables declared outside of the parallel region. You can find an extended exemplary description in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14381294/620382).