# Segmentation fault/longjmp causes uninitialized stack frame

Tags: fortran, openmp

The following code runs fine serially but running on a 64-core node of 230G results in "Segmentation fault/longjmp causes uninitialized stack frame" error. The OMP_STACKSIZE=30G is exported in the submission script. The parallelized section is given below.

```
!$omp parallel do shared (SEE) private (SKE,m,n,i,j,delta,inv_tau_delta,E, ek,eqv) REDUCTION(+:tot_delta,tot_inv_tau_delta)


        DO m=0,3100
         DO n=m,3100
           
           tot_delta=zero
           tot_inv_tau_delta=zero
           E=n*DeltaE

              DO i=1,Nk_BZ
               DO j=1,nbnd
               delta = w0gauss((E-ek(eqv(i),j))/degaussw)/degaussw
               inv_tau_delta=SKE(eqv(i),j,m)*delta
               tot_delta=tot_delta+delta
               tot_inv_tau_delta=tot_inv_tau_delta+inv_tau_delta
               ENDDO ! i
              ENDDO ! j
         
              SEE(n,m)=tot_inv_tau_delta/tot_delta
              SEE(m,n)=SEE(n,m)*exp((real(m-n))/kT)
         ENDDO
         ENDDO
```

The function w0gauss is defined at the end of the code. The array SKE has dimensions of SKE(44226,4,3100).

Is there a problem in the parallel section that could cause segmentation fault?

Thanks,
Vahid

I have increased the stack size from 10G to 30G.

Comment: Why do you need to have `SKE` (and `ek` and `eqv`) private? You are not modifying it in the parallel region, so it can be shared.

Comment: Also, I don't get the point of your reductions... They are not wrong, but apparently useless (these variables could be simply private).

Comment: How many threads are you using? If you run 64 threads, they will take 30*64=1920 Go just the stacks, which is impossible on a machine with 230 Go of memory. Remember that OMP_STACKSIZE defines the stack size *per thread*

Comment: 1. I declared SKE, ek and env private because their values change with changing loop index. I corrected this and declared them as shared.

Comment: In the following Stack Overflow link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360904/not-sure-what-should-be-shared-or-private-in-openmp-loop), Reduction clause is used for PE because it is an accumulator variable, similar to say tot_delta in my code. I have now declared them as private as you suggested.

Comment: In my submission script, I have #SBATCH --nodes=1, #SBATCH --cpus-per-task=64 and export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK. I made the mistake thinking that stack size is for the total stack and not per thread. Now I set it as 2G. I will try these changes to see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Are your arrays statically size? I strongly recommend to make them allocatable. That may also make the corresponding OpenMP temporary arrays to be allocated on the heap as well.  Fiddling with stack sizes makes everything so fragile. Strive to make your programs to behave in a robust way even if it makes them slower by a percent or two. It will save your personal time in the end.

Comment: The arrays are not allocated. For example, REAL(KIND=DP)    :: SEE(0:3100,0:3100) is how SEE is declared. I will make them allocatable to see what happens. So far, the seg-fault is avoided but SEE is sometimes positive, sometimes negative and mostly NaN. It should be always positive. Maybe the NaN comes from division by tot_delta.

Comment: I allocated the SKE, SEE and ek arrays before the omp block and deallocated it near the end of the code. The code crashed with segmentation fault. Without the allocation, it did not seg-fault.

Comment: To start, have you tried compiling and running the code without OpenMP? Are the results OK?

Comment: I have compiled and run without openmp but after 20 hours, the job did not finish. I printed out the loop indices m and n to see how long it will take to finish. My estimate is between 70 to 80 hours serially. That is why I am trying to parallelize it.

Comment: Maybe, but it's important to validate first the serial version of the code. There's no point searching a problem with OpenMP as long as you're not sure the serial version is OK. If necessary, you have to reduce `n` for the tests.

Comment: This code works fine serially on a smaller input file. I would be more than happy to provide the input files to demonstrate the validity of my statement. The smaller file containing SKE is several hundred Mb. I did not realize that parallelizing a 15-line code with OpenMP could be so complicated. I think I will switch to MPI with which I am more familiar. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: And on this smaller input file, how does behave the OpenMP version? Correct or wrong results? It also seems that the code you have posted is not the one you are currently running. Could you post an updated version?

Comment: If you are getting a segfault, it means that your code is broken. It does not mean that allocatable arrays are bad. Allocatable arrays are the way to go in general. Only use large static arrays when really needed (=very rarely if at all).

Comment: I allocated the arrays after reading the input files, which caused the segfault. With correct allocation, the parallel code works fine on the smaller input data and agrees with the serial output. However, for the larger input (6Gb), some of the SEE are NaN. Hopefully I can resolve this by playing with the number of threads or memory.

Comment: This discussion leads nowhere, as you changed the code several time, while the posted code is still the initial one.

Comment: As I mentioned in my last comment, the issue of "Segmentation fault" has been resolved by allocating the arrays and not statically declaring them. As for the NaN results with larger input, I mentioned in my earlier comment that  I will try to resolve this on my own. So please consider this thread as resolved. Thank you for all your comments. It was a learning experience.